# Return 1 Record from 3 joined tables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, inner-join

i have this query

```
select DISTINCT outcome.outcome_id as N'id', SName as N'dir', Summry as N'summry', notes as N'note',category as N'cat', outcome_date as N'date' from outcome
inner join Incomeuser on outcome.outcome_id=Incomeuser.outcome_id
inner join Senders on Incomeuser.Senders_id=Senders.Senders_id
```

it's Return 3 Records with the same id
All I want is the first Record for each unique ID :)
like i have this records :

- 106
- 106
- 106
- 260
- 270
- 260

it should return *106 - 260 - 270*,
**any help ?!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use strings for column aliases.  Especially when this is not needed.

There is no such thing as a "first" record in a SQL table or result set.  I assume you intend the earliest `outcome_date`.

You can use `top (1)` and `row_number()`:

```
select top (1) o.outcome_id as id, SName as dir, Summry as summry, notes as note, category as cat, outcome_date as date
from outcome o inner join
     Incomeuser iu
     on o.outcome_id = iu.outcome_id inner join
     Senders s
     on iu.Senders_id = s.Senders_id 
order by row_number() over (partition by o.outcome_id order by outcome_date) ;
```

Comment: that was very quick ..
Thanks man ♥ , that work for me , AND I NEED THE ALIASES BUT WHEN I POST THE QUESTION I EDIT IT .

Comment: @Lubbock the aliases are fine, it is making them look like nvarchar that is not needed. It just adds noise and confusion to your query. It provides no benefit to say N'id' instead of a simple id.

Comment: @SeanLange i need them for Arabic char

Comment: I would advise you not to use Arabic characters for aliases. But whatever, that is up to you.